# Python Very long string in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I am getting data from a csv file, using `data = numpy.recfromtxt('table.csv', delimiter=';', dtype=str)`

The table looks something like this:

```
Name; Birthdate; Biography
John; 1990; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?
```

Python and numpy seem to have a problem with this long strings.
Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: What kind of _problems_ are you talking about? You should clarify that.

Comment: `recfromtxt` uses the more common `genfromtxt`. 1st line has 2 delimiters. 2nd has 3.  How many fields do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas package of Python.

Here is a simple idea of using it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter = ";")
```

Hope this is what you want...

Comment: what did that produce?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use pandas package to read from csv

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
```

Pandas can handle long strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am having no problem reading it, so perhaps your question may be about formatting it in a fashion suitable for printing.  Here a few options.

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> a = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti; Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?"
>>> txt = textwrap.wrap(a, width=70)
>>> print(("{}\n"*len(txt)).format(*txt))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo
intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum,
inquam, abeunti; Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a
Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?
```

Or perhaps this one...

```
>>> txt2 = "\n".join([i for i in txt])
>>> print(txt2)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo
intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum,
inquam, abeunti; Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a
Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
In [67]: np.recfromtxt('stack40765849.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=str)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-eab6d3192d4d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.recfromtxt('stack40765849.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=str)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in recfromtxt(fname, **kwargs)
   1949     kwargs.setdefault("dtype", None)
   1950     usemask = kwargs.get('usemask', False)
-> 1951     output = genfromtxt(fname, **kwargs)
   1952     if usemask:
   1953         from numpy.ma.mrecords import MaskedRecords
...
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 3)
```

(Note, `recfromtxt` is using `genfromtxt`, which is discussed a lot.

The problem isn't the length of the string; it's with the number of delimiters.  The first line (a header?) has 2, suggesting you want 3 columns or fields.  But the 2nd line has 3; the extra may be part of the text.

Identifying the 1st line a field names gives the same error.

```
np.recfromtxt('stack40765849.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=str,names=True)
```

`pandas` loads this as:

```
In [74]: data=pandas.read_csv('stack40765849.txt',delimiter=';')
In [75]: data
Out[75]: 
      Name                                          Birthdate  \
John  1990   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi...   

                                              Biography  
John   Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur...
```

It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't look right.

==================

If I change the `;` in the text to `.`

```
In [82]: np.genfromtxt('stack40765849_1.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=None,names=Tr
    ...: ue)
Out[82]: 
array((b'John', 1990, b' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti. Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?'), 
      dtype=[('Name', 'S4'), ('Birthdate', '<i4'), ('Biography', 'S225')])
```

I get a structured array (almost like a recarray) with 3 fields; and the last is long - the full text.  (the `b'...'` denotes a byte strings in Py3; that won't appear in Py2 displays.)

`pandas` produces something similar:

```
In [83]: data=pandas.read_csv('stack40765849_1.txt',delimiter=';')
In [84]: data
Out[84]: 
   Name   Birthdate                                          Biography
0  John        1990   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi...
```

Correct Py3 unicode load:

```
In [91]: np.recfromtxt('stack40765849_1.txt', delimiter=';', dtype='U4,i,U255',n
    ...: ames=True)
Out[91]: 
rec.array(('John', 1990, ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Scrupulum, inquam, abeunti. Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a Chryippo. Quo tandem modo?'), 
          dtype=[('Name', '<U4'), ('Birthdate', '<i4'), ('Biography', '<U255')])
In [92]:
```